# BeautifulSoup: <div class <span class></span><span class>TEXT I WANT</span>

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the string enclosed by the span with id="titleDescription" using BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="itemText">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="itemPromo">Customer Choice Award Winner</span>
        <a href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116501" title="View Details" >
            <span class="itemDescription" id="titleDescriptionID" style="display:inline">Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz &#40;3.9GHz Turbo&#41; LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K</span>
            <span class="itemDescription" id="lineDescriptionID" style="display:none">Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz &#40;3.9GHz Turbo&#41; LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Code snippet

```
f = open('egg.data', 'rb')
content = f.read()
content = content.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
content = ''.join([x for x in content if ord(x) < 128])

soup = bs(content)

for itemText in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'itemText'}):
    wrapper = itemText.div
    wrapper_href = wrapper.a
    for child in wrapper_href.descendants:
        if child['id'] == 'titleDescriptionID':
           print(child, "\n")
```

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "egg.py", line 66, in <module>
    if child['id'] == 'titleDescriptionID':
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2Gf1h8RL (for the entire file)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HZNiRtkA (entire python script)

Comment: pastes aren't loading anymore btw

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'id':'titleDescriptionID'})
for span in spans:
    print span.string
```

In your code, `wrapper_href.descendants` contains at least 4 elements, 2 span tags and 2 string enclosed by the 2 span tags. It searches its children recursively.

Comment: there was a reason i choose my method: I need to parse multiple such chunks of HTML. I have uploaded the full original file to pastebin. I didn't do this earlier because bpaste.net was treating it as spam and the CAPTCHA didn't work (Internal Server Error). Anyway, using your method works nicely but for some reason it won't parse all the 'span'+attrs tags in that file - just the first one it finds.

Comment: It should just find the first one for I select the span with attribute id. The id is unique. If you want to select more spans choose a right attribute or no.@paleywiener

Comment: <div class="sell-price">\n<span id="lvLiveRates_ltSell_0" style="color:#216A00;"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 30180</span></div>

Comment: how can I get 30180 value ?

Answer (score 2):

`wrapper_href.descendants` includes any [`NavigableString` objects](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), which is what you are tripping over. `NavigableString` are essentially string objects, and you are trying to index that with the `child['id']` line:

```
>>> next(wrapper_href.descendants)
u'\n'
```

Why not just load the tag directly using `itemText.find('span', id='titleDescriptionID')`?

Demo:

```
>>> for itemText in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'itemText'}):
...     print itemText.find('span', id='titleDescriptionID')
...     print itemText.find('span', id='titleDescriptionID').text
... 
<span class="itemDescription" id="titleDescriptionID" style="display:inline">Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz (3.9GHz Turbo) LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K</span>
Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz (3.9GHz Turbo) LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K
```

Comment: i liked this answer better and it seemed to fit my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
pool = BeautifulSoup(html) # where html contains the whole html as string

for item in pool.findAll('span', attrs={'id' : 'titleDescriptionID'}):
    print item.string
```

When we search for a tag using BeautifulSoup, we get a BeautifulSoup.Tag object, which can directly be used to access its other attributes like inner content, style, href etc.