# BeautifulSoup: passing a function for ever tag and parsing text

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import re, sys
import requests
import time as ti
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url   = 'http://www.newegg.com'
user_agent = ('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)')


#http://www.newegg.com/Computer-Hardware/Store
#http://www.newegg.com/CPUs-Processors/Category/ID-34
#http://www.newegg.com/Processors-Desktops/SubCategory/ID-343
#http://www.newegg.com/Processors-Servers/SubCategory/ID-727
#http://www.newegg.com/Processors-Mobile/SubCategory/ID-759

header = {
          'Host':      'www.newegg.com',
          'User-Agent': user_agent,
          'Accept':
              'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
          'Referer': 'http://www.newegg.com/Processors-Desktops/SubCategory/ID-343',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'DNT': '1',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

login_data_1 = {
            'Pagesize' : '10',

}

def write_file(file, data):
    content = open(file, 'wb').write(data)


def get_page(s, req_type, url, header, params, data):
    r = s.request(req_type, url, headers=header, params=params, data=data)

    return r.text.encode('utf-8')

def login():
    s = requests.Session()

    #Send preparatory login cmd
    url = base_url +\
          '/Processors-Desktops/SubCategory/ID-343'
    lc_content = get_page(s, 'get', url, header=header, params=login_data_1, data=None)
    print(lc_content)
    write_file('egg.data', lc_content)

import re
pat = re.compile(b'titleDescriptionID[0-9]+')

f = open('egg.data', 'rb')
content = f.read()
content = content.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
content = ''.join([x for x in content if ord(x) < 128])

soup = bs(content)

import re
id_pat = re.compile('titleDescriptionID[0-9]*')
def description_id(tag):
    if tag.name == 'span':
       if tag.get('class'):
          if tag.get('class')[0] == 'itemDescription':
              if re.match(id_pat, tag.get('id')):
                 print(tag.string)

    if tag.name == 'strong':
      print(tag.string) 
    if tag.name == 'sup':
      print(tag.string)

items = soup.find_all(description_id)

#login()
```

Data:

```
    <div class="itemText">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="itemPromo">Customer Choice Award Winner</span>
            <a href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116501" title="View Details" >
                <span class="itemDescription" id="titleDescriptionID" style="display:inline">Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz &#40;3.9GHz Turbo&#41; LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K</span>
                <span class="itemDescription" id="lineDescriptionID" style="display:none">Intel Core i7-3770K Ivy Bridge 3.5GHz &#40;3.9GHz Turbo&#41; LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770K</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    <ul class="itemFeatures" ><li>&nbsp;22 nm Ivy Bridge 77W</li><li>&nbsp;8MB L3 Cache</li><li>&nbsp;4 x 256KB L2 Cache</li>
    </ul>   

        <ul class="featureList" >
            <li><b>Series:</b> Core i7</li><li><b>L2 Cache:</b> 4 x 256KB</li><li><b>L3 Cache:</b> 8MB</li><li><b>Manufacturing Tech:</b> 22 nm</li>
            <li><b>Model #: </b>BX80637I73770K</li>
            <li><b>Item #: </b>N82E16819116501</li>
            <li><b>Return Policy: </b><a href="http://www.newegg.com/HelpInfo/ReturnPolicy.aspx#39" target="_blank" title="CPU Replacement Only Return Policy(New Window)">CPU Replacement Only Return Policy</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="itemAction">



<ul class="price price-product-cells" >
    <li class="price-was " >

    </li>
    <li class="price-map"  ></li>
    <li class="price-current "  >


            <span class="price-current-label"></span>
            $<strong>319</strong><sup>.99</sup> 
            <span class="price-current-range"> 
                <abbr title="to">&ndash;</abbr> 

            </span>


    </li>

    <li class="price-save " >

    </li>
    <li class="price-note">


    </li>
    <li class="price-ship">Free Shipping</li>
</ul>
```

Any way to clean up: description_id()? Or a better way to achieve the same thing.

Using ***bs4*** I'm extracting the string for a particular tag where: *id=titleDescriptionID[0-9]+* but i also have to extract the price in **`<strong> and <sup>`**

In an earlier thread people suggested doing find_all() but i don't think you can pass a regex-object as a value:
[BeautifulSoup: <div class <span class></span><span class>TEXT I WANT</span>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613606/beautifulsoup-div-class-span-class-spanspan-classtext-i-want-span)

Which is why i decided to pass a function instead.

Comment: Please put the code and the smallest amount of data you can to demonstrate the problem in your post rather than external links.

Comment: The documentation for findAll explicitly says "The value of a key-value pair in the 'attrs' map can be a string, a list of strings, a **regular expression object**, or a callable..."

Comment: hmm.. i tried this: pat = re.compile('titleDescriptionID[0-9]+')
print(soup.find_all('span', {'id':pat})) and could have sworn it didn't work, but now it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can pass a regex object:

```
>>> soup
<html><body><span id="1"></span><span id="2"></span><span id="3"></span></body></html>
>>> soup.find_all('span', id=re.compile(r'\d'))
[<span id="1"></span>, <span id="2"></span>, <span id="3"></span>]
>>>
```

So you can use `soup.find_all('span', id=re.compile(r'titleDescriptionID[0-9]+')`.